# Processes in screen stop working after idling for a while (Raspberry pi 4)

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

so i have very weird problem, when I start process in screen on raspberry pi 4, everything works fine, but after i disconnect, after like 30 minutes of idle, this process freezes. The only way to be unfrozen its, when i just login back from putty and its unfreeze. The process i start its Spring Boot app. So what i think its like some kind of sleep or i don't know. I am using raspberry pi 4, 4gb ram version with installed rasbian lite, also if its needed i am using it only for remote access, no hdmi cable its plugged in. Hope someone helps me, i'll be very glad.

Comment: What is the "Spring Boot" app trying to do? Do you get the same issue if you use another long running command? e.g. `top`

Comment: No i don't have issue. The string boot its backend which can be accessed by link and check some file hanshes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I used system service and added the spring to boot with my raspberry and all got resolved, so thanks anyway.